# Efficiently add trailing newline to JSON ByteString emitted by Aeson when writing to file

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, lazy-io

By default, Aeson `encode` or `encodePretty` do not append a trailing newline to the `ByteString`.  I.e., when viewing the resulting file in vim I see the `[noeol]` indicator.

What is a performant/idiomatic way to append a newline to the file?

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for `Main.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty
import           GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal  as BS

data ExampleRecord =
  ExampleRecord {
       field1 :: String
     , field2 :: String
       } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON ExampleRecord

main = L.writeFile "foo.json" $ encodePretty (ExampleRecord "a" "b")
```

with accompanying `myproj.cabal` file:

```
name:                myproj
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable emit-json
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:
      base >=4.8 && <4.9
    , aeson
    , aeson-pretty
    , bytestring
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I am able to append a newline to `foo.json` by using the [`snoc` function from `ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:snoc), changing the last line in `Main.hs` to this:

```
main = L.writeFile "foo.json" $ encodePretty (ExampleRecord "a" "b") `L.snoc` BS.c2w '\n'
```

However, the `snoc` documentation describes this as an O(n) operation.  Should there be a way to append this newline in constant time?

Comment: The idiomatic solution is to use `Data.ByteString.Builder` - and note that `aeson-pretty` provides a function `encodePrettyToTextBuilder :: ToJSON a => a -> Builder` so you are pretty much good to go - appending to the end of a `Builder` is constant time. Alternatively you could sequence writes to the file instead of appending to the string (e.g. `withFile f $ \h -> hPutStr h (encodePretty ...) >> hPutStr h "\n"`), but (in my opinion) this is not as idiomatic as using a builder (simply due to being impure).

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I then used the implementation of `writeFile` from `Data.Text.Lazy.IO` instead of from `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.